# SQLAlchemy changing table name to have two underscores

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Flask/SQLAlchemy project, I have an index table called Styles_Index, which has a corresponding table object that I query on.
The schema in sqlite3 looks like

```
CREATE TABLE Styles_Index
(
    beer_id integer not null, 
    style_id integer not null, 
    primary key (beer_id, style_id)
);
```

And the object in python looks like

```
class Styles_Index(db.Model):
    beer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('beers.id'),
            primary_key = True)
    style_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('styles.id'),
            primary_key = True)
```

When I try to join the table onto another that shares a common key via the SQLAlchemy BaseQuery.join(), it creates a query:

```
SELECT styles__index.id AS styles__index_id, 
    styles__index.beer_id AS styles__index_beer_id, 
    styles__index.style_id AS styles__index_style_id
    FROM styles__index JOIN styles ON styles__index.style_id = styles.id
    LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

where Styles_Index has two underscores instead of one.
Is this an intentional design choice due to the _ wildcard character in SQL? Is there a better way to write this query, without resorting to writing raw SQL?

Comment: Normal python class syntax is to use Class case i.e StylesIndex (as per PEP 8), is that an option?

Comment: It is certainly an option, I'll give that a try and see what happens. I'd rather not change my table names if I can avoid it though.

Comment: See what table names it produces vs the syntax.

Comment: It looks like changing the class name to the PEP 8 standard did indeed fix the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome, I wrote it as an answer in case anyone else comes googling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, using PEP 8 specific names such as MyClassName, will not have such an issue.

Comment: any explanation on why it does this as the default behavior? it seems like using underscores in table names shouldn't cause such an issue

Comment: @MattW the issue is uppercase,  which becomes  _ + lowercase .  And since you already have one underscore, you end up with double.

Answer (score 1):

Flask-SQLAlchemy will automatically generate a table name from the model class name if neither `__tablename__` nor `__table__` are defined on the model class.

The generation function ([camel_to_snake_case](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/2cbd26f995cc7ccf5b6400179ae47eeda35a02be/src/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py#L197)) uses a regular expression substitution ([link](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/2cbd26f995cc7ccf5b6400179ae47eeda35a02be/src/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py#L199)) which inserts an underscore before some internal uppercase letters and then downcases the result. Thus a class name with an underscore before an internal uppercase letter results in a name containing a double-underscore.